# How do I indent a code block in Quip?

Tags: source-code

I have a bulleted list, and I want to insert an indented code block:

[image]

When I try to insert a code block, and then use `tab` to indent, I end up with:

[image]

In other words, the code block is not indented, it broke the list (notice the next "a" instead of "b"), and the tab was captured by the code block and inserted spaces instead of indenting the beginning of the code block.

I've tried dragging the block, indenting it, converting the current bullet's style, etc, but nothing worked.

I've seen indented code blocks before. How do I create them?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Paste a text from a code block into your list.

---

You need to create a `list code block` (not an official name, but what I'm going to use to reference it) or a code block that is embedded in a list. This is different from a normal code block in that:

- Instead of inserting spaces when `tab` is pressed, it indents/unindents the entire block.
- The block appears within a list item and can be indented.

The only downside with a `list code block` is that it must have a bullet. There doesn't seem to be a way to both indent a block and not have it take up a bullet. The only workaround is to add it as a subitem of where you're trying to insert it.

The only way I've found to create a `list code block` is to copy text from a code block (it could even be one character), and then paste it into your list. You can then indent it if you don't want it to use up a bullet number:

[image]